# Xubuntu 23.04, as well as other versions, not connecting to WiFi

Tags: networking, xubuntu, internet, ethernet

I have used a virtual machine previously for any and all of my linux needs, however times have changed and I've been in need of a laptop with a linux OS installed on it. Just to stick with what ive gotten used to, I installed xubuntu and ran into one problem, the laptop wouldnt connect to my WiFi without an ethernet connection. Now this in itself isn't bad for at home, but I intend to take it with me to uni, where I doubt I will be sitting that close to any router in class, hence where my issue arises.

Whenever I attempt to connect to any wireless internet, it rejects my and doesn't let me do anything network related, besides editing the details of the connection. However, once connected via ethernet it works like a charm. Furthermore, after disconnecting the ethernet, it would continue to be disconnected until I restart/turn off the machine, or until it just randomly disconnects.

I have experienced this issue now with multiple different Xubuntu and Ubuntu versions, don't know if its just my laptop or I'm missing something.